# Loop over data frame to get quantiles and identify outliers

Tags: r, loops

Not sure why I am getting this wrong

```
structure(list(peso1_v00 = structure(c(97.8, 102.9, 78.4, 80.4, 
82.5, 92.6, 99, 66.8, 91.8, 70), label = "Peso: 1a determinación", format.spss = "F5.1"), 
    cintura1_v00 = structure(c(120, 123.2, 104, 106, 117.7, 115, 
    123, 93.5, 116.7, 109), label = "Cintura: 1a determinación", format.spss = "F5.1"), 
    tasis2_e_v00 = structure(c(139, 123, 138, 143, 160, 167, 
    139, 134, 161, 145), label = "TA: tensión arterial 2: sistólica", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    tadias2_e_v00 = structure(c(74, 65, 75, 55, 75, 76, 65, 64, 
    62, 79), label = "TA: tensión arterial 2: diastólica", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    p17_total_v00 = structure(c(7, 5, 9, 5, 8, 9, 4, 10, 10, 
    10), label = "Cuestionario de 17 puntos: Suma de puntuación de P17", format.spss = "F3.0"), 
    geaf_tot_v00 = structure(c(0, 1286.71, 5524.48, 419.58, 198.14, 
    839.16, 3188.81, 993.94, 2386.01, 3636.36), label = "AF: Gasto energético en actividad física total (MET•min/sem)", format.spss = "F8.2"), 
    glucosa_v00 = structure(c(116, 152, 113, 257, 108, 119, 108, 
    112, 141, 102), label = "Analítica: Glucosa en mg/dL", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    albumi_v00 = structure(c(4.57, 4.71, 4.85, 4.43, 4.44, 4.59, 
    4.6, 4.56, 4.45, 4.59), label = "Analítica: Albúmina en g/dL", format.spss = "F6.2"), 
    coltot_v00 = structure(c(261, 197, 235, 168, 217, 248, 155, 
    254, 265, 326), label = "Analítica: Colesterol total en mg/dL", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    hdl_v00 = structure(c(71, 43, 38, 36, 57, 49, 54, 60, 48, 
    60), label = "Analítica: Colesterol HDL en mg/dL", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    ldl_calc_v00 = structure(c(147, 135, 161, NA, 145, 155, 73, 
    157, 172, 222), label = "Analítica: LDL calculado en mg/dL si trigli<=300", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    trigli_v00 = structure(c(217, 93, 179, 315, 73, 219, 138, 
    186, 223, 220), label = "Analítica: Triglicéridos en mg/dL", format.spss = "F5.0"), 
    hba1c_v00 = structure(c(6.29, NA, 5.63, 12.17, NA, 6.11, 
    5.9, 5.68, NA, 6.16), label = "Analítica: Hemoglobina glicosilada (HbA1c %)", format.spss = "F5.2"), 
    i_hucpeptide_v00 = structure(c(854.34, NA, 1485.59, 4241.95, 
    NA, 847.89, 1524.39, 1265.48, NA, 290.22), label = "Hu C-peptide (72) IMIM S'han substituit en les següents var els codis de inf i sup a limit de detecció per el limit inf i sup de detecció", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 13L), 
    i_hughrelin_v00 = structure(c(681.94, NA, 480.11, 1587.73, 
    NA, 453, 263.93, 392.98, NA, 1327.91), label = "Hu Ghrelin (26) IMIM", format.spss = "F7.2", display_width = 10L), 
    i_hugip_v00 = structure(c(2.67, NA, 2.67, 2.67, NA, 2.67, 
    2.67, 2.67, NA, 2.67), label = "Hu GIP (14) IMIM", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 9L), 
    i_huglp1_v00 = structure(c(177.37, NA, 202.62, 519.02, NA, 
    200.13, 163.82, 20.29, NA, 14.14), label = "Hu GLP-1 (27) IMIM", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 9L), 
    i_huglucagon_v00 = structure(c(387.58, NA, 591.73, 855.29, 
    NA, 726.99, 430.35, 389.59, NA, 336.04), label = "Hu Glucagon (15) IMIM", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 11L), 
    i_huinsulin_v00 = structure(c(278.72, NA, 538.29, 1693.25, 
    NA, 299.75, 608.35, 397.7, NA, 129.17), label = "Hu Insulin (12) IMIM", format.spss = "F7.2", display_width = 10L), 
    i_huleptin_v00 = structure(c(2518.28, NA, 12175.88, 12369.5, 
    NA, 8409.76, 5998.71, 9298.52, NA, 5919.57), label = "Hu Leptin (78) IMIM", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 9L), 
    i_hupai1_v00 = structure(c(3084.08, NA, 2650.85, 3202.18, 
    NA, 3085.25, 3410.73, 3109.79, NA, 1375.07), label = "Hu PAI-1 (61) IMIM", format.spss = "F7.2"), 
    i_huresistin_v00 = structure(c(4758.94, NA, 3594.11, 13564.63, 
    NA, 3221.72, 2864.01, 3630.63, NA, 2827.01), label = "Hu Resistin (65) IMIM", format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 9L), 
    i_huvisfatin_v00 = structure(c(8.64, NA, 2081.59, 2363.58, 
    NA, 2989.72, 653.96, 1129.24, NA, 631.11), label = "Hu Visfatin (22) IMIM", format.spss = "F9.2", display_width = 6L), 
    col_rema_v00 = structure(c(43, 19, 36, NA, 15, 44, 28, 37, 
    45, 44), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 14L), homa_v00 = structure(c(1436.96, 
    NA, 2703.41, 19340.68, NA, 1585.34, 2920.08, 1979.66, NA, 
    585.57), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L), ln_trigli_v00 = structure(c(5.38, 
    4.53, 5.19, 5.75, 4.29, 5.39, 4.93, 5.23, 5.41, 5.39), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 15L), 
    ln_homa_v00 = structure(c(7.27, NA, 7.9, 9.87, NA, 7.37, 
    7.98, 7.59, NA, 6.37), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 13L), 
    ln_hba1c_v00 = structure(c(1.84, NA, 1.73, 2.5, NA, 1.81, 
    1.77, 1.74, NA, 1.82), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 14L), 
    ln_geaf_tot_v00 = structure(c(NA, 7.16, 8.62, 6.04, 5.29, 
    6.73, 8.07, 6.9, 7.78, 8.2), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 17L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to carry out is detection of points outside a certain range

```
colvars <- c("peso1_v00", "cintura1_v00", "tasis2_e_v00" , "tadias2_e_v00" ,   "p17_total_v00", "geaf_tot_v00"  ,   "glucosa_v00", "albumi_v00", "coltot_v00", "hdl_v00", "ldl_calc_v00", "trigli_v00", "hba1c_v00", "i_hucpeptide_v00", "i_hughrelin_v00", "i_hugip_v00", "i_huglp1_v00", "i_huglucagon_v00", "i_huinsulin_v00", "i_huleptin_v00", "i_hupai1_v00", "i_huresistin_v00", "i_huvisfatin_v00", "col_rema_v00", "homa_v00",  "ln_trigli_v00", "ln_homa_v00", "ln_hba1c_v00", "ln_geaf_tot_v00")

i=1
for (i in 1:length(colvars)) {
  
  q<-sapply(outliers_v00[ ,i], quantile, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm =T)
  iqr<-sapply(outliers_v00[ ,i], IQR, na.rm =T)
  up <-  q[ , i[2]]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
  low<- q[ ,i[1]]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range
  remained<- subset(outliers, outliers[ ,i] > (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers[ ,i] < (q[2]+1.5*iqr))
  eliminated<-subset(outliers_v00, outliers_v00[,i] < (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers_v00[,i] > (q[2]+1.5*iqr))

}
```

Even simplifyng the loop till

```
i=1
for (i in 1:length(colvars)) {
  
  q<-sapply(outliers_v00[ ,i], quantile, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm =T)
  iqr<-sapply(outliers_v00[ ,i], IQR, na.rm =T)
}
```

I don't get both quantiles, in fact I get the same value (not correspondant with anything) for both Q25 and Q75

Without loop I get the vector with values

```
  q<-sapply(outliers_v00[ ,i], quantile, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm =T)
```

But afterwards for the expression **remained** and **eliminates** I could not make the iteration work. I know there are alternatives, but I want to learn how to refer to columns  [, i]

Comment: You need to return something and assign the new values to a new position of for example, a list . create a list (e g my_quantiles <-list() ), then assign the vectors to each list element, e. g.  by doing my_quantiles[i]<- your quantile vector

Comment: also, in this case much better just to use lapply on your data frame directly.

Comment: is there a reason you are putting all your column names into colvars? or could you actually just use `colnames(outliers_v00)`?

Comment: @tjebo I don't really get what you are suggesting.
rg255 you are right. I did it this way to scrutinize the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perhaps take this approach - `sapply()` taking the outliers_v00 data, it will work through each variable applying the function specified. Here it is a custom function returning the quantiles and IQR as a vector. The output from `sapply()` is then transposed with `t()` to put it a more intuitive way around, and returned as a `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(t(sapply(outliers_v00, function(j){
  c(quantile(j, probs=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=TRUE), IQR(j, na.rm=TRUE))
})))
```

You can then get lists of the values that are inside and outside of the range with this - note it excludes NA values to the excluded list, and a list is appropriate as vector lengths differ (some variables keep all their values, others do not so it is not god for a data.frame)

```
out <- data.frame(t(sapply(outliers_v00, function(j){
  c(quantile(j, probs=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=TRUE), IQR(j, na.rm=TRUE))
})))

out$low <- out[,1] - (out[, 3] * 1.5)
out$up  <- out[,2] + (out[, 3] * 1.5)

remained <- sapply(1:length(outliers_v00), function(j){
  outliers_v00[, j][outliers_v00[, j] >= t(out)[4, j] & outliers_v00[, j] <= t(out)[5, j] & !is.na(outliers_v00[, j])]
})

eliminated <- sapply(1:length(outliers_v00), function(j){
  outliers_v00[, j][!(outliers_v00[, j] >= t(out)[4, j] & outliers_v00[, j] =< t(out)[5, j])]
})
```

---

Side note on the use of `T` and `F` - it is better practice to use `TRUE` and `FALSE` - `T` and `F` can have their meaning overwritten and that could cause havoc, e.g.

```
T <- FALSE
if(T) print("hello")
```

Comment: It worked with for getting the results but the problem is how you manage later to loop through it and get the expressions:
  remained<- subset(outliers, outliers[ ,v] > (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers[ ,v] < (q[2]+1.5*iqr))
  eliminated<- subset(outliers_v00, outliers_v00[v] < (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers_v00[v] > (q[2]+1.5*iqr))

Comment: There you go - sorry, missed that part of your post

Answer (score 2):

It's your usage of sapply which is incorrect, also try another subsetting. Also, you need to assign your loop result to a new list element.

The idea is - either use sapply or lapply, or a for loop. You won't need both. I'd directly loop over the data frame with lapply.

```
## define list first
my_quantiles <-list()

## you can and should directly loop over the length of your data frame - the columns are the same as your colvars vector. This is much safer. 
for (i in 1:length(outliers_v00)) {
## no sapply needed
## subset without a comma. 
  q <- quantile(outliers_v00[i], probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm =T)
  iqr <- diff(unname(q))

up <-  q[2] + 1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
low<- q[1] - 1.5*iqr # Lower Range

## I've slightly simplified your subsetting, also included equal to expression
remained <- outliers_v00[[i]][outliers_v00[[i]] >= low & outliers_v00[[i]] <= up]
## i think you want an "OR" operator here
eliminated<- outliers_v00[[i]][outliers_v00[[i]] < low | outliers_v00[[i]] > up]

## add both vectors to the correct list position
my_quantiles[[i]]<- list(quantiles = q, IQR = iqr, remained = remained, eliminated = eliminated)
}

my_quantiles

#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$quantiles
#>  25%  75% 
#> 78.9 96.5 

#> [[1]]$IQR
#> [1] 17.6

#> [[1]]$remained
#>  [1]  97.8 102.9  78.4  80.4  82.5  92.6  99.0  66.8  91.8  70.0

#> [[1]]$eliminated
#> numeric(0)


#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$quantiles
#>     25%     75% 
#> 106.750 119.425 
...
```

Better to directly loop over your data frame. Advantage is: Much less code, no subsetting needed, therefore much less likelihood of loop-confusion, and you will have the column names "for free".

```
lapply(outliers_v00, function(x) {
q <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm =T)
iqr <- diff(unname(q))
c(q, IQR = iqr)

## etc
}
)

#> $peso1_v00
#>     25%     75%     IQR  
#>    78.9    96.5    17.6 

#> $cintura1_v00
#>     25%     75%     IQR 
#> 106.750 119.425  12.675 
...
```

Comment: Now I get what you said
However the point of all this syntax is to get 
up <-  q[ , i[2]]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
  low<- q[ ,i[1]]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range
  remained<- subset(outliers, outliers[ ,i] > (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers[ ,i] < (q[2]+1.5*iqr))
  eliminated<-subset(outliers_v00, outliers_v00[,i] < (q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & outliers_v00[,i] > (q[2]+1.5*iqr))

Comment: @JavierHernando see update! I think you might wanna read about subsetting. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html

Comment: I get it. Thank so much, I am very grateful. The disadvantage is that te resulting list does no include variable names.
The apply method, would it be possible to achieve what you got with the loop?
Ok I've seen what posted the colleague, so the answer is that